# CiviCRM & Wordpress remove links from recurring contributions section of front end user dashboard and related contacts dashboard

Tags: wordpress, user-dashboard, links, organization

I desperately need assistance on something.

I have a CiviCRM installation on a WordPress site.

The issue is that on the front end User Dashboard under recurring payments, there are four links can be seen, Cancel, Change Billing Details, and for related contacts Dashboard, View and Edit. These links are all live but the functions don't work on Change Billing Details and we don't want the View and Edit links to be visible on related contacts. I have played with various permission settings for View and Edit but that does not seem to affect the links showing up with live links on them.

We would like to leave the Cancel link in place as this function works perfectly and remove Change Billing Details and View and Edit.

I have looked through a lot of the templates and I can't seem to find out where to make the changes so I can add in custom templates.

Can someone please assist me with this and point me in the right direction for removing these links from the front end.

Any assistance would be highly appreciated

Comment: have you compared on the demo to identify if it's a setting related to your instance or to CiviCRM in general. Sometimes that helps. hope you'll find!